# How to fix the Out of stock bug in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, product, stock

Magento shows products that are in stock as “Out of Stock”.

I wonder what's the origin of this problem and how can I fix it

Comment: please provide site link.

Comment: your product page not open?

Comment: Yes it causes that problem too (yesterday it was working perfectly but since today all products are out of stock and products page shows 404 error)

Comment: hey can you tell me what configuration you have used for your server, you website is fast....i want this features on my site also.

Comment: can i access your admin?

Comment: can you tell me how to create fast website in magento.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try and re-index the website. Go to admin -> System Config -> Index Management -> Select `Stock Status` and hit `Reindex Data`. That could do the trick. Otherwise, the issue may be more complex.